# Find all possible values of c

Tags: number-theory, integers

A triple of integers $(a,b,c)$ satisfies $a+bc=2017$ and $ b+ca=8$. Find all possible values of $c$

---

I have applied subtraction and addition to these 2 equations which resulted $2c= \frac {2025}{a+b} - \frac{2009}{a-b} $. Since  $a+b$ has 15 distinct values and $a-b$ has 6 distinct values , if I do the combination, the value of $2c$ will be 80 values which is so much to write. So, is there any method?

Comment: what about $bc+c^2a=8c\implies a-c^2a=2017-8c\implies a=\frac{2017-8c}{1-c^2}$?

Comment: And only satisfied when c=0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the 2 equations to get $(a+b)(c+1)=2025$, from which you can then get the factors and hence the possible values for $c+1$.

Similarly, subtract the 2 equation and you'll get $(c-1)(b-a)=2009$, and do the same here to get another set of possible values of $c-1$. Here, the values of $c$ we get are $-2008,-286,-48,-40,-6,0,2,8,42,50,288,2010$.

Now any value of $c$ that is admissible, must satisfy both the above equations.Thus,of these values of $c$ we just found, only $c=-6,0,2,8$ satisfy the first equation. Hence these are the only values of $c$ satisfying **both** the equation.

Comment: Yeb , and it has 15 answers. When I do the subtraction , it shows other 6 answers . So , is that it?

Comment: @NovemberftBlue yeah, that's all you have to do. Since they asked only for possible values of $c$ this problem becomes much easier. You need to look at subtraction too and take the intersection of values

Comment: @NovemberftBlue I completed the solution, and explained it a bit more

Comment: I got it , thank you:D

Comment: But $c=0$ could be the answer too

Comment: @NovemberftBlue ah yes, it's because i missed the case $c-1=-1$ (I forgot all the negative factor cases too, i'll edit it soon)

Comment: Thank you:) ! And don’t forget the answer c=0 and “ only 4 values of c “

Comment: @NovemberftBlue  yeah I fixed it. Though there were silly errors in my answer, I hope you understood the intuition behind the method?

Comment: Yeah I do , because I had followed your method before ,I thought it was too much , so I tried to find other ways. But anyway , Thank you. I appreciate it .